# Validación de dos decimales

Tags: html5, angular

Quiero poner solo 2 decimales, osea que me permita ingresar cualquier número pero 2 decimales.
Estoy usando angular y en mi componente coloco :

```
** public  validacion(event) { 
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
}**
```

y en el HTML

```
**<div class="col-md-3">
<label>Monto:</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="jugador.monto" name="monto" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" 
(keypress)="validacion($event)"  required />
                            </div>**
```

pero no funciona quiero que salgo un ejemplo 2.22

Comment: Los decimales son obligatorios u opcionales? Puede haber un único decimal? Este número sería correcto: `2.`?

Comment: Hola, porque no utilizas el paquete de angular denominado `ngx-currency`? Si te sirve de algo aquí te dejo un demo para que revises si te sirve o no. [aquí](https://nbfontana.github.io/ngx-currency/) y el paquete lo puedes encontrar en esta [sección](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-currency)

Answer (score 0):

Con substr puedes lograrlo, lo que hace es cortar cadenas dada una posicion inicial y una posicion final, primero valido si existe un punto en el valor, luego corto la cadena de la posicion inicial al punto (parte entera) y le concateno desde el punto hasta 2 posiciones mas (decimal).

indexOf me trae el valor del indice dentro de la cadena

```js
var validarNumero= function(e) {
  var valor = e.value;
  e.value = (valor.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (valor.substr(0, valor.indexOf(".")) + valor.substr(valor.indexOf("."), 3)) : valor;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="validarNumero(this)" />
```

Comment: Añadir una explicación y no solamente código haría más fácil de entender tu aporte y seguro que será mejor recibido